# Kotlin hide appbarlayout inside fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, toolbar

I have 1 activity and 4 fragments attached to it. I have an appbarlayout in my activity. My goal is to hide this appbarlayout in certain fragments. Is it possible? How should I write a code?

> Activity.kt

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.newsNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
```

Comment: There is a onDestinationChange listener in navController. You can use that and check if the current destination is the same destination in which you don't need appBarLayout and can update the visibility.

Comment: can you write a sample code block sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   //if you want to handle multiple fragments use switch instead of if.
   if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
        //current Fragment is the fragment you want and do what ever you want with the appBar 
   } else {
       //current Fragment is not the fragment you want
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I have connected the navcontroller to the bottomnavigationview here. However, I cannot access other fragments in this structure. How can I access them?

Comment: Can you explain more about other fragments?